# error when deploying OLAP cube in spagoBI. message: cannot deploy document on server: class it.eng.spagobi.sdk.exceptions.SDKException

Tags: business-intelligence, spagobi, fiware-knowage

error when deploying OLAP cube in SpagoBI. 
error message: cannot deploy document on server: class it.eng.spagobi.sdk.exceptions.SDKException

Answer (score 10):

1. Open `template.xml` file as any editor you like.
2. Then there is an Hierarchy element, where it has `hasAll` element which configured wrongly.
3. So, update `hasAll=true` then save.
4. Deploy `template.xml` on SpagoBI server.

Comment: I love when I have no clue what the problem is and then I find the simplest of answers here on SO! Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you very much. This was excactly